# AWS S3 download file from Flask

Tags: python, amazon-s3, flask, boto3

I have created a small app that should download file from a AWS S3.

I can download the data correctly in this way:

```
 s3_client = boto3.resource('s3')
 req = s3_client.meta.client.download_file(bucket, ob_key, dest)
```

but if I add this function in a flask route it does not work anymore. I obtain this error:

ClientError: An error occurred (400) when calling the HeadObject operation: Bad Request

I'm not able to figure out why it does not work inside the route. Any idea?

Answer (score 2):

That is related to your AWS region. Mention the region name as an added parameter.

Try it on your local machine, using

```
aws s3 cp s3://bucket-name/file.png file.png --region us-east-1
```

If you are able to download the file using this command, then it should work fine from your API also.

Comment: I tried to specify the region in s3_client = boto3.resource('s3', region_name='eu-central-1') and now I get as error a 403.

Comment: I saw your answer above. That was an unexpected error :P

Answer (score 1):

The problem was that with flask I needed to declare s3_client as global variable instead of just inside the function.

Now it works perfectly!